# JavaFX: setDisable(true) DatePicker problems

Tags: javafx, datepicker

I am trying to disable certain dates from a datepicker in javafx (v10) however I keep getting the issue whereby the valid dates seem to change css when moving forwards a month and back. Is this a known bug or can anyone spot a fault with the code?

```
private void getDayCellFactory(DatePicker datePicker1) {

    Callback<DatePicker, DateCell> dayCellFactory = (final DatePicker datePicker) -> new DateCell() {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (item.isAfter(LocalDate.now().plusDays(9))) {
                setDisable(true);
            }
            if (item.isBefore(ChronoLocalDate.from(LocalDate.now()))) {
                setDisable(true);
            }
        }
    };

    datePicker1.setDayCellFactory(dayCellFactory);
}
```

Comment: I have updated the post the version is JavaFX 10 and to explain the valid dates for example could be 28,29,30,31 move forward a month and back then the valid dates grey out like they are disabled but are clickable. I remove the setDisable(true); and the datepicker no longer has the bug but means I loose the main feature I want, being the disable certain dates.